# Unable to login into any account

Tags: xubuntu, login, lightdm, login-screen

How it happened

My computer was becoming very unresponsive and I could not close any applications to free memory so I held the power button until the computer turned off. When I turned it on everything was ok except everytime I write my password the screen turns black some numbers such as #ff7e00 appear and the login screen pops up again. The computer was in some sort of login loop.

Lesson learned - never use the power button to power off.

What I've tried so far

- I have deleted `/.Xauthority` to no avail
- I have tried to login as guest but also guest faces the same infinite login loop
- I have created a new account but I am unable to log into it as it also faces the same loop
- I have reinstalled **LightDM** but it wont login
- I have installed and switched to **GDM** but it also wont login
- I have installed and switched to **XFCE** from the default Ubuntu but it also wont login
- I have changed ownership (`chown`) of `/home`, `home/user`, `/.Xauthority` etc.

What I have not done

- Download and install **Gnome** (isn't this doing the same as installing **XFCE**)
- Download and reinstall **Ubuntu**

Can someone please help me login to my account and/or explain what happened to cause this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Open the boot options and then try to open your system in advanced->recovery mode and if it opens then remove the password using the GUI choose the options from the settings to log into directly and then again try the normal boot. This might help.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. When I go to recovery mode and try to  open failsafe graphic mode i get a fatal error no screens found. when i try to repair broken packages it says it cannot find archive.ubuntu.com